# Create a dataframe with list elements with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my dataframe:

```
    df<-list(structure(list(Col1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Col2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("B", "C", "D", "F", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "E", "H", "M", "N", "P"), class = "factor"), 
    Col2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("B", 
    "C", "D", "F", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)), structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "W", "H", "M", "T", "U"), class = "factor"), 
    Col2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("B", 
    "C", "D", "S", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)))
```

I want to extract col1=`df[[1]][1]` as a dataframe. Then col1 of the second position of this list I want to merge to the `df[[1]][1]`, then I will have a dataframe with 2 columns.
After this I want to merge the column 1 of the third position of the list to the dataframe with two columns, then I will have a dataframe with 3 columns.

In other words my dataframe should have 3 columns, all the first columns of each entry of my list.

The dplyr package can helpme to do this?

Any help?

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara I edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to extract the three columns named `"Col1` in one go. Then set the names of the result.

```
col1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, '[[', "Col1"))
names(col1) <- letters[seq_along(col1)]

col1
#  a b c
#1 A A A
#2 B M M
#3 C N U
#4 D P T
#5 E E W
#6 F H H
```

Choose any other column names that you might find better.

A `dplyr` way could be

```
df %>% 
  unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  select(., starts_with("Col1"))
#  Col1 Col1.1 Col1.2
#1    A      A      A
#2    B      M      M
#3    C      N      U
#4    D      P      T
#5    E      E      W
#6    F      H      H
```

Answer (score 5):

With `map_dfc` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

map_dfc(df, `[`, 1)
```

**Output:**

```
  Col1 Col11 Col12
1    A     A     A
2    B     M     M
3    C     N     U
4    D     P     T
5    E     E     W
6    F     H     H
```

Comment: Or even just `map_dfc(df, "Col1")` or `map_dfc(df, 1)`

Comment: @CalumYou Both of these give error: Error in cbind_all(x) : Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL]. because `map(df, 1)` returns a list of vectors, not list of dataframes

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, see my [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414323/7028459) in complementary answer. Using purrr 0.2.5

Comment: Note that `map_dfc(df, 1)` does not work with `dplyr_0.7.4` but my solution does.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative use of `map_dfc` making use of `purrr`'s concise element extraction syntax that allows specifying elements of elements by name or position. The first is, for example, equivalent to

```
map_dfc(df, `[[`, 1)
```

which differs from the use of `[` in that the columns will not be named variations of `Col1` and just get `V` names instead, which may be desirable since names like `Col11` and `Col12` may be confusing.

```r
df <- list(structure(list(Col1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Col2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("B", "C", "D", "F", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)), structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "E", "H", "M", "N", "P"), class = "factor"), Col2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("B", "C", "D", "F", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)), structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "W", "H", "M", "T", "U"), class = "factor"), Col2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("B", "C", "D", "S", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)))

library(purrr)
map_dfc(df, 1)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   V1    V2    V3   
#>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 A     A     A    
#> 2 B     M     M    
#> 3 C     N     U    
#> 4 D     P     T    
#> 5 E     E     W    
#> 6 F     H     H
map_dfc(df, "Col1")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   V1    V2    V3   
#>   <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1 A     A     A    
#> 2 B     M     M    
#> 3 C     N     U    
#> 4 D     P     T    
#> 5 E     E     W    
#> 6 F     H     H
```

Created on 2018-09-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Gives the same error: Error in cbind_all(x) : Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL]. and I also have purrr_0.2.5

Comment: Hmm, strange. I would investigate more but I think I have the expected behaviour, you are free to do so on your end? Can you do `bind_cols(list(1:2, 3:4))`, since, the `dfc` just calls `dplyr::bind_cols` anyway?

Comment: nope, both `bind_cols(map(df, 1))` and `bind_cols(list(1:2, 3:4))` give me the same error. My explanation that the elements need to be datafames come from Hadley's response in this issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1389 not sure if it's by design or a bug. I would think that it is by design since Hadley has been a fan of type-stable functions. Not sure why it works for you.

Comment: Also looks like a bug from this issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/395

Comment: OK, it turns out I had `dplyr_0.7.4`, which still had the issue. Updating to `dplyr_0.7.6` solved the issue. Since `bind_cols` come from `dplyr`, updating `purrr` didn't help. Maybe you should make a note about this solution not working for `dplyr` versions before 0.7.6

Comment: Ok, that sounds great! Yeah I was confused because `?bind_cols` has "In addition to data frames, you can supply vectors" in the examples

Answer (score 1):

```
res<-1:nrow(df[[1]][1])

for(i in 1:length(df)){
  print ( as.vector(df[[i]][1]))
  res<-cbind(res,as.data.frame(df[[i]][1]))
}
res$res<-NULL
```

So, the output is:

```
  Col1 Col1 Col1
1    A    A    A
2    B    M    M
3    C    N    U
4    D    P    T
5    E    E    W
6    F    H    H
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  sapply('[[',1) %>%
  as.data.frame
#returns
  V1 V2 V3
1  A  A  A
2  B  M  M
3  C  N  U
4  D  P  T
5  E  E  W
6  F  H  H
```

Comment: This is basically Rui's answer with pipes, there's nothing `dplyr` about it.

Comment: @avid_useR  I see, should I remove it then?

Comment: Unless you have something else to show, I don't think this adds any value to Rui's answer